# Understanding the return this in carasoul.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery/JS in general. I was just going through the code of [carasoul.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/carousel.js#L169), and came across the following lines of code:

```
  Carousel.prototype.slide = function (type, next) {
    var $active   = this.$element.find('.item.active')
    var $next     = next || this.getItemForDirection(type, $active)
    var isCycling = this.interval
    var direction = type == 'next' ? 'left' : 'right'
    var that      = this

    if ($next.hasClass('active')) return (this.sliding = false)

   // A LOT MORE CODE 

    isCycling && this.cycle()

    return this
  }
```

My difficulty is with understanding the `return this` in the end, why this line of code? If you go through the carasoul.js plugin the `slide()` function gets called inside the function `next()` and `prev()`.

Now a lot of functions in the plugin return results, eg. the `getItemForDirection()` function.

```
  Carousel.prototype.getItemForDirection = function (direction, active) {
    
    // SOME CODE AND CALCULATIONS

    return this.$items.eq(itemIndex)
  }
```

I understand that a result needs to be returned, but in the slide() function, why is this being returned?

I was reading [this article](http://javascriptissexy.com/beautiful-javascript-easily-create-chainable-cascading-methods-for-expressiveness/), it's about JS chaining, but somehow I don't understand the practical usage of `return this` in the slide function.

What does this do?

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Answer (score 0):

It is used for calls chaining. You can do something like this with chaining:

```
carouselInstance.slide().next().cycle().to(5);
```

On the other hand `getItemForDirection()` method should return some item so it can not be used in such case.

Comment: i understand that part , but i don't understand the chaining in context of carasoul.js

Comment: I've modified my example to show you more advanced chaining in carousel. It can be useful for example if you want to set carousel on pause after going to the particular slide: `carouselInstance.slide().pause();`